# How to match a dataset based on a variable distribution of an other dataset?

Tags: r, distribution

Let say I've two datasets with similar variables but different distribution. In the example below, dataset `a` has a variable `var1` with a mean of 10 and a sd of 4. Dataset `b` has also variable `var1` but with a mean of 8 and a sd of 4.

```
a <- data.frame(id=1:500,var1=rnorm(500,10,4),type="a")

b <- data.frame(id=1:300,var1=rnorm(300,8,4),type="b")

rbind(a,b) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=type,y=var1)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Is there a way to filter dataset `b` to match dataset `a`'s `var1` distribution ? When I say `match`, mean and sd should be similar (not necessarly equal)

I tried using `MatchIt` package to match a and b dataset but it filters also some entries from dataset `a`.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Edit>

Here's the real shape of `a` and `b` density (from my data). `a` is red, `b` is blue

[image]

Comment: you want to filter it or resample it? `nrow(b) < nrow(new_b)`?

Comment: is it specifically when a and b are normally distributed?

Comment: only filter. Not specifically when a and b are normally distributed.